# Is it possible to read a script value?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python. I have a question can I read a script value with python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url='https://www.iltelegrafolivorno.it/cronaca/radi-vandalico-vetrate-dustrutte-cecina-1.6231324'


r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('script')[9]["cp30"])
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking about. Are you trying to find all of the `<script>` tags in an html document?

Comment: I try to extract the value of cp30 = polopolyweb-free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to parse the javascript yourself. For this particular value, the simple script below works. For other values such as arrays or objects, parsing will be not as simple.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.iltelegrafolivorno.it/cronaca/radi-vandalico-vetrate-dustrutte-cecina-1.6231324'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find_all('script'):
    if not e.string: continue
    for line in e.string.splitlines():
        if 'cp30' in line:
            _, value = line.split(':')
            value = json.loads(value)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you suggest me where I can learn how it works?

Comment: Well, you can add `print(e.string)` just after `value = json.loads(value)` to see what's in the script tag. The rest is just basic string processing which should be covered by most tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

`cp30` only occurs and a simple regex will work:

```
import requests, re

print(re.search(r'cp30":\s?"(.*?)"', requests.get('https://www.iltelegrafolivorno.it/cronaca/radi-vandalico-vetrate-dustrutte-cecina-1.6231324').text).group(1))
```

[image]